# Python write() function is writing previous data to next file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, text-files

I am reading text from a text file then reformatting that text to write to different text files.

The text that I am reading is the following, `testFile.txt`:

```
                  *******************************
                  *  Void Fractions in the Bed  *
                  *******************************

     Z(m)    MIN.FLUIDIZ.  EMULSION    TOTAL

0.0000E+00  0.4151E+00  0.8233E+00  0.8233E+00
0.1000E-09  0.4151E+00  0.8233E+00  0.8233E+00
0.1000E-05  0.4151E+00  0.8233E+00  0.8233E+00
0.2000E-05  0.4151E+00  0.8233E+00  0.8233E+00
0.1251E+01  0.4151E+00  0.9152E+00  0.9152E+00
0.1301E+01  0.4151E+00  0.9152E+00  0.9152E+00
0.1333E+01  0.4151E+00  0.9152E+00  0.9152E+00


               *************************************
               *  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *
               *************************************

     Z(m)    VOID FRACTION

0.1333E+01  0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01  0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01  0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01  0.9992E+00
0.3533E+01  0.9992E+00
0.3633E+01  0.9992E+00
0.3733E+01  0.9992E+00
0.3833E+01  0.9992E+00
0.3933E+01  0.9992E+00
0.4000E+01  0.9992E+00


           *********************************************
           *  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *
           *********************************************

     Z(m)    MIN.FLUIDIZ.  ACTUAL

0.0000E+00  0.1235E+00  0.4911E+01
0.1000E-09  0.1235E+00  0.4911E+01
0.1000E-05  0.1235E+00  0.4911E+01
0.2000E-05  0.1235E+00  0.4911E+01
0.3000E-05  0.1235E+00  0.4911E+01
0.1151E+01  0.1235E+00  0.4915E+01
0.1201E+01  0.1235E+00  0.4915E+01
0.1251E+01  0.1235E+00  0.4915E+01
0.1301E+01  0.1235E+00  0.4915E+01
0.1333E+01  0.1235E+00  0.4915E+01
```

Below is my Python code to parse the text file:

```
openFile = open('testFile.txt','r')

groupOneFile = open('groupOneFile.csv','w')
groupTwoFile = open('groupTwoFile.csv','w')
groupThreeFile = open('groupThreeFile.csv','w')

idx = 0;
firstIdx = 0;
secondIdx = 0;
thirdIdx = 0;

for line in openFile:

    # first group
    if '*  Void Fractions in the Bed  *' in line:
        print line
        firstIdx = idx

    if idx in range(firstIdx+5,firstIdx+43):
        line = line.lstrip()
        line = line.replace('  ',',')
        groupOneFile.write(line)

    # second group
    if '*  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *' in line:
        print line
        secondIdx = idx

    if idx in range(secondIdx+5,secondIdx+43):
        line = line.lstrip()
        line = line.replace('  ',',')
        groupTwoFile.write(line)        

    # third group
    if '*  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *' in line:
        print line
        thirdIdx = idx

    if idx in range(thirdIdx+5,thirdIdx+43):
        line = line.lstrip()
        line = line.replace('  ',',')
        groupThreeFile.write(line)

    idx += 1

openFile.close()

groupOneFile.close()
groupTwoFile.close()
groupThreeFile.close()
```

The `groupOneFile` should have the following data in it:

```
0.0000E+00,0.4151E+00,0.8233E+00,0.8233E+00
0.1000E-09,0.4151E+00,0.8233E+00,0.8233E+00
0.1000E-05,0.4151E+00,0.8233E+00,0.8233E+00
0.2000E-05,0.4151E+00,0.8233E+00,0.8233E+00
0.1251E+01,0.4151E+00,0.9152E+00,0.9152E+00
0.1301E+01,0.4151E+00,0.9152E+00,0.9152E+00
0.1333E+01,0.4151E+00,0.9152E+00,0.9152E+00
```

The `groupTwoFile` should have the following:

```
0.1333E+01,0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01,0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01,0.9992E+00
0.1333E+01,0.9992E+00
0.3533E+01,0.9992E+00
0.3633E+01,0.9992E+00
0.3733E+01,0.9992E+00
0.3833E+01,0.9992E+00
0.3933E+01,0.9992E+00
0.4000E+01,0.9992E+00
```

And so on for the `groupThreeFile`.

The reading of the main text file and writing the data to the other files is working fine. The problem is the data that is written to the `groupOneFile` is also being written to the beginning of the other files `groupTwoFile` and `groupThreeFile`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You should probably post some example input and output to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: just wondering. For every `for` loop iteration should there only be one write to a file??

Comment: As a side note, instead of setting `idx = 0` and then `idx += 1` each time through the loop, just use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate): `for idx, line in enumerate(openFile):`.

Comment: I think this is way too much code for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @gnibbler any suggestions on more efficient code is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that working you could just initialize

```
firstIdx = 1000000
secondIdx = 1000000
thirdIdx = 1000000
```

because the problem is that if you set them to `0` then the first lines will be in range for all groups.

Note however that this code is very inefficient... a better approach could be:

```
outputFile = None

for line in openFile:
    if '*  Void Fractions in the Bed  *' in line:
        idx = 0; outputFile = groupOneFile
    elif '*  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *' in line:
        idx = 0; outputFile = groupTwoFile
    elif '*  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *' in line:
        idx = 0; outputFile = groupThreeFile

    if outputFile and 5 <= idx < 43:
        line = line.lstrip()
        line = line.replace('  ',',')
        outputFile.write(line)

    idx = idx + 1
```

In Python if you write `if x in range(a, b):` a check for every element is done (or in Python 2.x an actual list of all integers from `a` to `b-1` is built) each time you do the test. Much better is to write the test as `if a <= x < b:`.

Note also that `2.5 in range(0, 10)` would return false (while of course `0 <= 2.5 < 10` is true).

In Python there is no `switch` statement, but you can build a dispatching table instead:

```
filemap = [('*  Void Fractions in the Bed  *', groupOneFile),
           ('*  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *', groupTwoFile),
           ('*  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *', groupThreeFile)]

outputFile = None
for line in openFile:
    for tag, file in filemap:
        if tag in line:
            idx = 0
            outputFile = file
    if outputFile and 5 <= idx < 43:
        outputFile.write(line)
    idx += 1
```

if exact match is possible (instead of `in` testing) this can be made even better using a dictionary:

```
filemap = {'*  Void Fractions in the Bed  *': groupOneFile,
           '*  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *': groupTwoFile,
           '*  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *': groupThreeFile)}

outputFile = None
for line in openFile:
    f = filemap.get(line.strip())
    if f:
        # Found a new group header, switch output file
        idx = 0
        outputFile = f
    if outputFile and 5 <= idx < 43:
        outputFile.write(line)
    idx += 1
```

Comment: This looks much better. I'm new to Python so is there an equivalent to the `switch` method in Objective-C? Instead of using a bunch of `if` statements in Python.

Comment: @Gavin: In Python there is no `switch`. You've to use `if-elif-elif-...-else`. You can also use a dispatch map... se edit.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for my suggestion, so here it is

```
from itertools import groupby, product

groups = {'*  Void Fractions in the Bed  *': 'groupOneFile.csv',
          '*  Void Fractions in the Freeboard  *': 'groupTwoFile.csv',
          '*  Superficial Velocities in the Bed (m/s)  *': 'groupThreeFile.csv'}

fname = None

with open('testFile.txt','r') as fin:
    for k, group in groupby(fin, lambda x:x[0].isspace()):
        if k:
            for i, g in product(group, groups):
                if g in i:
                    fname = groups[g]
                    break
        else:
            with open(fname, 'w') as fout:
                fout.writelines(','.join(s.split())+'\n' for s in group)
```

Answer (score 0):

`secondIdx` and `thirdIdx` begin at 0, which means that `if idx in range(secondIdx+5,secondIdx+43):` is triggering on lines that are close to the top of the file.

To fix this, you could either rewrite to a more stateful setup (when you read `Void Fractions in the Bed`, you write to the first file until you find a new heading, etc.) or simply initialize your `Idx`s to `-100` or so.